# iOS Missing grant_type

Tags: ios, http, post, oauth

I'm getting {"error_description":"Missing grant_type parameter value","error":"invalid_request"} when trying to request access token for the first time. My code is below:

```
let params : [String : String] =
    ["client_id" : clientID,
        "client_secret" : secret,
        "redirect_uri" : redirectURL,
        "code" : code,
        "grantType" : "authorization_code"
    ]
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("aapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("\(request.HTTPBody!.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
```

What might be the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I don't want to sound harsh, but there are multiple issues with this code.

You are not sending `grant_type`, but you do send `grantType`.

You are encoding the post body as `application/json`, but you are setting the Content-Type to be `aapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded` which seems to be a misspelling of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So two possible spelling issues and a content type mismatch.

Work out if you need to send [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1) or [application/json](http://json.org/). Format the data and set the content type as needed.

Double check the spelling of everything.

Comment: @Supsup i am also facing the same error. can you tell me how did you clear the issue please?

Comment: @Jeffery Thomas can you help me

Comment: Please help me in that   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033645/error-missing-required-parameter-grant-type-using-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment77040871_45033645