# Error 'Missing required parameter : grant_type' using Swift 3

Tags: ios, twitter, swift3

I am working on Twitter API and I want to get access_Token but I am getting this error:

```
{
"errors" : [
  {
    "message" : "Missing required parameter: grant_type",
    "label" : "forbidden_missing_parameter",
    "code" : 170
  }
 ]
}.
```

My request is below:

```
let dict = ["grant_type" : "client_credentials"]  

requestPOSTURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", params: dict as [String : AnyObject] , headers: ["Authorization" : "Basic " + strHeader, "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"], success: { (json) in

        Helper.sharedInstance.Print(json as AnyObject)

    }, failure: {(error) in

        Helper.sharedInstance.Print(error as AnyObject)
    }). 

func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    sessionManager.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
        //print(responseObject)
        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to get access_Token (OAuth) but not able to get because above errors are coming.

Comment: And what's `AFWrapper`? Alamofire? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801102/error-invalid-request-error-description-required-parameter-is-missin ?

Comment: Yes it is Alamofire.

Comment: [Parameters on the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type are ignored. In particular, this MIME type does not support the charset parameter.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) Try removing `charset`.

Comment: Alamofire directly supports [Basic Authentication](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#authentication). Don't add the header directly, use Alamofire's `authenticate(usingCredential:)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue, and it get fixed with native NSMutableURLRequest.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59472862/1528061