# using twitter api to get token

Tags: javascript, twitter, ecmascript-6, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use the twitter api, but need to get authentication. There are 2 types , and I only need `Application-only authentication aka app only`.  This is the type of authentication where an application makes API requests on its own behalf.

The docs explain to use this method, you need to use a bearer token. You can generate a bearer token by passing your consumer key and secret through the POST oauth2 / token endpoint.

Here is the [link to docs explaining this endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only). There is even an example request but still it isn't very clear to me what needs to be done.

I have an API key and API secret key, but am getting the following error:

> body: ‘{“errors”:[{“code”:170,“message”:“Missing required parameter:
>   grant_type”,“label”:“forbidden_missing_parameter”}]}’ }

My server side code looks like this

```
var request = require('request');
var btoa = require('btoa');

const KEY = encodeURIComponent('1234');
const SECRET = encodeURIComponent('5678');

request({
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${KEY}:${SECRET}`),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    uri: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    body:  JSON.stringify({
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials' // I am passing the grant_type here
    })
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log('res', res)
  });
```

The CURL request in the docs looks like the following:

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
User-Agent: My Twitter App v1.0.23
Authorization: Basic eHZ6MWV2R ... o4OERSZHlPZw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 29
Accept-Encoding: gzip

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Twitter does not support CORS so yes it needs to be made server side. I think you may be missing something regarding hashing the Consumer Key and Secret appended together with a : in between, though.

Comment: yeah, I have narrowed it down to just using server side requests now, but still can't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To to this there were a couple of things. First the request needed to be made server side. You need to install `btoa` from npm to provide the encoding of the key and secret key. The KEY and SECRET need to be separated by a colon. The body of the request needs to be a string of

`'grant_type=client_credentials'`

See full code example below.

```
const btoa = require('btoa');

request({
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${KEY}:${SECRET}`),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    uri: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    const token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 5

```
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

        let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
        let twitterConsumerKey : String = (info?["TwitterConsumerKey"] as? String)!
        let twitterConsumerSecret : String = (info?["TwitterConsumerSecret"] as? String)!

        let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", twitterConsumerKey, twitterConsumerSecret)
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

        let urlString = NSString(format: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
        print("url string is \(urlString)")
        let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.url = NSURL(string: NSString(format: "%@", urlString)as String) as URL?
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 30
        request.httpBody = "grant_type=client_credentials".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {data, response, error -> Void in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                let receivedData = data else {
                    print("error: not a valid http response")
                    return
            }

            switch (httpResponse.statusCode)
            {
            case 200:

                let response = NSString (data: receivedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)


                if response == "SUCCESS"
                {

                }

            default:
                print("save profile POST request got response \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                let str = String(decoding:data!, as: UTF8.self)

                print(str)

            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
```

The problem is with the format of http body of request. I was wrongly using dictionary of `grant_type : client_credentials` instead of string `grant_type= client_credentials`.

> request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:
>   ["grant_type" : "client_credentials"], options: [])